# Como cambiar el color de las lineas verticales de un tema de VS Code

Tags: vscode

Estoy usando el tema 2077 y las lineas verticales cuando anido no se ven. Quiero hacer que se vean o en su defecto cambiarles el color para verlas sin tenér que estár en la linea y no se como hacerlo, alguien me da una mano? es mi tema favorito y no quiero cambiarlo solo editar eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es como yo las veo actualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que no hay una forma simple de arreglar eso. Te tocará modificar el tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una carpeta en la raíz llamado `.vscode`.

Adentro crea un archivo llamado `settings.json`
y pega lo siguiente:

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorIndentGuide.background": "#e7e7e799"
  }
}
```

Ahí tu elige el color que más te guste.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución un poco complicada pero efectiva:

1. Dirígete hacia donde se encuentran guardadas las extensiones, típicamente en `%userprofile%\.vscode\extensions\`.
2. Busca la carpeta de la extensión que posee el tema a modificar. En este caso se llama `endormi.2077-theme-1.5.2`
3. Entra a la carpeta **themes**.
4. Abre el archivo .json del tema con algún editor de código o texto.
5. Modifica las propiedades que necesites. Notarás que se encuentran en formato JSON así que deberás respetarlo.

La propiedad que estás buscando es la siguiente:

```
"editorIndentGuide.background": "#hexColor"
```

Cambia `hexColor` por el color que quieras en formato hexadecimal.

Puedes dirigirte a la [documentación oficial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) para ver detalladamente qué es lo que modifica cada propiedad.

Para concluir, debo mencionar que probablemente pierdas los cambios hechos luego de actualizar la extensión, así que te aconsejo que hagas una copia del archivo en un lugar seguro. Luego puedes recuperar los cambios simplemente con reemplazarlo.

Comment: También puedes optar por hacer los cambios por proyecto como enseñó Esteban Carrera o en el archivo de preferencias de usuario.